# (open-wrt) Accessing clients from another connected router?

Tags: networking, openwrt

I have a cable modem with WiFi and one LAN port. The LAN port is connected to WAN port of ethernet router (one with openwrt). On the ethernet router, I have clients(NAS is one of them). The problem is I cannot access these clients wirelessly from the WiFi/cable modem. Can you tell me the specific config I need?

The cable modem has `10.0.0.1` address. The ethernet router is assigned `10.0.0.10` on cable modem's LAN. Now, on ethernet router's LAN, it has address `192.168.0.1` whereas my NAS has address `192.168.0.50`. Both of them have subnet mask `255.255.255.0`.

I can access ethernet router's page on `10.0.0.10` from the WiFi/cable modem but not on `192.168.0.1`

Comment: It could be a bit clearer question. It seems that you have 2 LANS - ethernet one is connected via router to the wifi router (that probably is also a DSLmodem). Is the openwrt router acting as a bridge? So are both computers on the same subnet? I am guessing again - probably not. What ports to forward, also depends on protocol you are using for file access - again I am guessing it is SAMBA - windows, but it is unclear. You could give IP addresses + subnet masks for the systems involved. Finally - a simple solution would be to use openwrt router as a bridge.

Comment: Sorry for not providing the complete info. Basically, I have a cable modem with WiFi and one LAN port. The LAN port is connected to WAN port of ethernet router (one with openwrt). On the ethernet router, I have clients(NAS is one of them). The problem is I cannot access these clients wirelessly from the WiFi/cable modem. Can you tell me the specific config I need?

Comment: Yes, much clearer now. I am guessing that ethernet router does not have a wifi interface, or does it? I am a bit curious why you are using openwrt in that case. Basically you could use the router as a bridge, if you want your LAN behind the router to be seen by your wifi clients ( that are going through the modem then). What is your router model?

Comment: And this page contains all info you might need. https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/networking/network.interfaces

Comment: Yes, it does has WiFi but its too crappy. Is there a way it can act as both? A WiFi router and as a bridge? Its a tp-link 841n

Comment: I figured it out! thanks! In wan interface, I bridged eth1 and eth0 and in lan interface, I made wlan the master

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your settings are currently. Your Cable modem has a router built into it and is acting as a 'Gateway'. To keep from both trying to play the roll of 'Gateway'
First check Wireless Mode in Wireless > Basic Settings and see that it is on "Client Bridge" 
[image]
Look at what your Operating Mode in Setup > Advanced Routing
and see that it is set to "Router" First. If this doesn't work try changing
it to " Gateway"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is to create a bridge that will bind together both the subnet behind the router and the one between the modem and the router. So you should bridge the WAN interface on the router with the LAN interface and you are set. For details you could look here. https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/networking/network.interfaces